# Issue with conflict in Gemfile when using spree_fancy and spree_core 2.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm new to spree and I've got an issue with installing spree_fancy. Any help with resolving my issue would be appreciated!

I'm following the spree tutorials and have a problem with the second one:
1. getting_started_tutorial.html
2. extensions_tutorial.html

I am getting this error when I add spree_fancy to my gemfile and run the command bundle install:

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
    In Gemfile:
    spree_fancy (>= 0) ruby depends on
    spree_core (~> 1.3.0) ruby

    spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on
    spree_core (2.0.3)
```

========================================

## My gemfile looks like this:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

    gem 'sqlite3'

    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'

    gem 'spree', branch: '2.0.3'
    gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
    gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
```

========================================
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use spree_fancy from the 2-0-stable branch.  Try the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree_fancy', :github => 'spree/spree_fancy', :branch => '2-0-stable'
```